# Boundary of a star-shaped domain in spherical coordinates

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, spherical-coordinates

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a bounded domain that contain the origin and, is star-shaped with respect to the origin too. Is it true that, in spherical coordinates, $\partial \Omega$ is given by $r=r(\omega)$ so that $r$ is a function of the angle only?

Comment: Do you mean that there is a unique boundary point in the direction $\omega$ from the origin? Then no, consider a segment through the origin.

Comment: No. $ \Omega$ is star-shaped w.r.t. the origin (by definition) means containing every line segment  starting from the origin and ending at $x$,  $\forall x\in \Omega$. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain )

Answer (score 1):

As N.Bach said, the answer is negative. For example, in $n=2$ take the unit disk minus the segment $[1/2, 1]$. This is a star shaped domain with respect to the origin but  its  boundary is not given as $r=r(\theta)$.

To have boundary representation $r=r(\theta)$ it suffices to assume that there exists a neighborhood of origin such that $\Omega$ is star-shaped with respect to every point in that neighborhood.

Comment: On that segment (on the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$ in Cartesian coordinates) $r=\frac{1}{2}\sec{\theta}$. Obviously $r=r(\theta)$ may not be smooth, but still a valid representation.

Comment: if....,You know of a reference for the sufficient condition you give ?

Comment: @Medo : The segment between $A(1/2,0)$ and $B(1,0)$, which is a portion of the X-axis. Then the boundary of the domain is precisely the unit circle plus that segment. The points of the segment have polar coordinates $(\rho,0)$ with $1/2\le\rho\le 1$. So for angle $0$, there are multiple boundary points.

Comment: @if. I see. But would that be still a star-shaped domain. I am concerned now about the points $(\rho,0)$
with $\rho>\frac{1}{2}$. Does the line segment from the origin to any such point still lie entirely in Ω ?

Comment: @Medo : guess I'll answer while `if....` is still away. In that specific case, you don't have to worry about those points because they do not belong to $\Omega$, so you don't have to look at those line segments, so $\Omega$ is still star-shaped.
My other example in the comment I gave to your question was a simple line segment that contains the origin. Segments are convex thus star-shaped wrt to any of their point. Because segments are flat, they are their own boundary. In polar coordinate, there are at most two distinct angles so you can't have a boundary description of type "$r=r(\theta)$".

Comment: Thanks a lot N. Bach. I voted up your comment. Actually your very first comment was very clear and enough as well. I am sorry I only got it now.